# Cross compilation "toolset"

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

What exactly is a cross-compilation "toolset" or "toolchain"? I understand the need for a cross-compiler when generating code for another platform, but what exactly is understood by a "toolset"?

For example, when compiling boost libraries, there are several toolsets, such as "mingw", "gcc" or "msvc" - what is the difference in the compiled libs/dlls between these toolsets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cross-toolchain is the whole tool collection, containing the cross-compiler itself, the linker and other necessary tools, like make templates and the libraries to link your program with. optionally it also can contain debugger tools, like gdb-server, buildscripts.

Answer (score 1):

Its a package/toolbox with more than just gcc such as cross ar, ld , as, nm, objdump, ranlib, strip, c++, gdb etc.,

many times you need to compile your own glib etc.,

anything with ms sounds like microsoft stuff. gcc is the opensource linux stuff.
You can learn about different platforms and 
you can also produce your own cross tool using kegel's jail setup : http://kegel.com/crosstool/crosstool-0.43/buildlogs/